# HiddenFor value is not posted back to the controller after POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have spent a lot of time to find a workaround or a solution for the problem that I have. I have an AJAX form like the prototype below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = Model.MyID.ToString(), OnSuccess = "onSuccess" 
}))
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>    

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyID, new { @id = Model.MyID.ToString() })

}
```

As you see, the HiddenFor value is updated based on the value that comes from within the POST action like the code snippet below from the POST action:

```
return Content(model.MyID.ToString());
```

The good thing is that the AJAX call updates the HiddenFor value but in the next POST action, the value of MyID is zero despite I do know it must be something non-zero!

I read a lot of posts suggesting `Model.Clear()` or `Model.Remove("MyID")`, etc. but they even did not help!

What am I doing wrong and what is the firm solution for this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you show some more code

Comment: Please post the Controller action code...

Comment: You don't provide any code showing that you are updating `model.MyID`. You are returning `model.CompetencyId`, try updating `Model.MyID` in your post method, because the hidden field has the value of `model.MyID` and changing the value with the ajax result will not update anything in your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I belive that the best and cleanest way is to follow the following article to populate HiddenFor element:

http://slushanthan.blogspot.ca/2013/04/simple-aspnet-mvc-ajax-form-application.html

It neither requires ModelState clean up nor other action-side stuff. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify [InsertionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.insertionmode%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), default is replace. It looks like you replacing hidden input by plain text from controller. 
Check Network tab in chrome/firefox developer toolbar during ajax request. There could be also helpful Elements tab to check html after request.

edit:

example:
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Test2(Test2Model model)
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            var random = rnd.Next(10000).ToString();
            var response = string.Format("<input id=\"MyID\" name=\"MyID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{0}\">", random);
            return Content(response);
        }
```

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test2", "Form", new AjaxOptions() { 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "replaceid" 
}))
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="submit"/>

    <div id="replaceid">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyID)
    </div>
}
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, the purpose is to replace the value based on a new value.

Comment: InsertionMode.Replace will replace content of div not value of input. You can do what you want by wrap input in div and return input code from controller. Check example i've added above.

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot to provide model at GET method in controller,